# android windowSoftInputMode scrollview style

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

i have one problem.I try to explain it.this is a xml code:

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:background="#ffffff"
 >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/u_set_pin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/u_widget_height"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:textColor="#4c4c4c"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/u_done_margin_buttomt"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/logo_red"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i have very simple view.image in top position and Edittext in bottom position in scrollview.everythink is perfect but i have problem some divises.
when i run my program some divices my image has gone(moved up on screen) and some divises images size has changed(i don't want to change size)
i searched about my problem and i found this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.CheckPinCodeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
    </activity>
```

i use this android:windowSoftInputMode in my activity but nothink changed
how i can solve my problem? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks evryone

Comment: Have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`?